# Why does this give an Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, dom-events, typeerror

```
var hatIds = [113333065] //This is the Ids
var PriceWanting = 15 //This is the price


var Loop = setInterval(function(){
        for (var Id in hatIds) {
                var hatLink = "http://m.roblox.com/items/" + hatIds[Id] + "/privatesales"
                $.get(hatLink,function(data){
                        var Regex = /\<span class="currency-robux">([\d,]+)\<\/span\>/
                        var PriceSelling = data.match(Regex)[1]
                        PriceSelling = Number(PriceSelling.replace(",",""))
                        if (PriceSelling <= PriceWanting) {
                                var Regex2 = /<a href="\/Catalog\/VerifyTransfer\DuserAssetOptionId=([\d,]+)\Damp;expectedPrice=([\d,]+)">/
                                var HatBuyId = data.match(Regex2)[1]
                                var HatBuyLink = "http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/VerifyTransfer?userAssetOptionId=" + HatBuyId + "&expectedPrice=" + PriceSelling
                                var Explorer = document.createElement('iframe');
                                function Buy(){
                                        Explorer.contentDocument.forms[0].submit();
                                };
                                Explorer.onload = Buy;
                                Explorer.width = "300";
                                Explorer.height = "400";
                                Explorer.src = HatBuyLink;
                                document.body.innerHTML = "";
                                document.body.appendChild(Explorer);
                                clearInterval(Loop)
                        }
                });
        }
        console.log("!")
},0)
```

For some reason, I seem to be getting an Uncaught TypeError. I don't know why and would like some help in fixing it.

Comment: Did you fall asleep on the `a` key?

Comment: Please tag the language you use.

Comment: Looks like a massive array `var hatIds = [113333065]`

Comment: I think this is javascript, @paxdiablo I thinks he's just irritated with the error :D